# How do I place an image over a div that contains JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've started using Codepen for fun, and I wanted to try my hand out at this JavaScript code called "Croppie"(I'm new and still learning JavaScript).

I want to place an image on top of the `div` that contains the JavaScript. But the image does not show up and gets hidden behind the `div`. I also want to be able to move the image in the `viewport` even with the image on top of it.

I've tried messing around with the `z-index`, but the image I want on top keeps getting hidden behind the `div`. [Here is the CodePen.](https://codepen.io/tinybirdcute/pen/wxoPyJ) (It wouldn't let me post without putting any code in my question so this is what I'm talking about in the CSS).

```
.mask {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://eprogramers.com/triangle.gif');
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#demo-basic {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript `<script>` tags are location non-specific.  Place them in the `<head>` tag or after the `</body>` tag in HTML documents.  A lot of JavaScript's power comes from the fact that it plugs into the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), allowing you to manipulate HTML page elements.  Read up on that for a better understanding of how to implement JS code.

Comment: @BrianPeacock thank you so much for the info!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and congrats on learning JavaScript. It is fun, rewarding, and can pay the bills too. No one ever seems to call attention to what a great thing it is when someone embarks on a new journey of learning and experiences or how hard that is to do. It is commendable!

Comment: @sukiyo No problem.  That is what StackOverflow is for :-)  Keep at it!

Answer (score 2):

I changed the style of `mask` CSS class as follows:

```
.mask{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url('http://eprogramers.com/triangle.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Please check the following code snippet:

```js
//create a variable called basic, the variable attaches to div called demo-basic, which is an instance of croppie
var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie({
  //awknowledge the viewport
    viewport: {
        width: 150,
        height: 200
    }
});

//basic variable.croppie binds with url of cat
basic.croppie('bind', {
    url: 'https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/demo/cat.jpg',
    points: [0,0,0,0]
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: pink;  
}

.mask{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url('http://eprogramers.com/triangle.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
}

#demo-basic {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.2"></script>

<script src="https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.js"></script>

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.css" />

<div id='demo-basic'>
  <div class="mask"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! do you know how to make the image in the viewport move even when the mask is placed over it? is there a way to attach the mask to the demo-basic croppie in the JS?

Comment: I don't think the croppie library have triangle support.

Comment: I just mean having any image over croppie. (the triangle image is an example), thank u tho!